# NoReverseMatch at /add_post

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a blog site using django and I made a way to add post within the home page without going to the admin page but when I post using the new way I get this error

[image: The error]

This is my models.py file

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=3500)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title + " | " + str(self.author))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-view", args=(str(self.id)))
```

This is the views.py file

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView
from .models import Post


class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "detail_view.html"


class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "add_post.html"
    fields = "__all__"
```

This is the polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-view'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
]
```

This is the add_post.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>Adding Post</title>
</head>

<h1>Add Blog Posts</h1>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Post</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you try to replace `path('add_post', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),` with `path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like this is caused by the model's `get_absolute_url` `reverse` `args=()`. I changed the below code in `models.py` from:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-view", args=(str(self.id)))
```

Into

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-view", args=[self.id])
```

The problem seems to be `args=()`, it is iterating over the `str(self.id)`. So `id=10` would actually be returned as a `tuple (1,0)`. I also removed the `str()` around the `self.id` since the URL takes in an `int`.

Comment: There is a screen shot of the error message, Thanks for helping

Comment: There are some files which I didn't show the home.html file and the detail_view.html file shall I display the code in it

Comment: Okay answer should help now